# Geometrical Brownian motion Passage time

Tags: brownian-motion, stochastic-analysis

Recently I have been self-studying stochastic analysis. One of the exercises was to calculate the probabilty of Brownian motion reaching certain level before time T given that W(t)=x. This wasn't that particulary hard. My question is, is there any way to calculate same thing for geometrical brownian motion? 
That is, calculate the probability that geometrical brownian motion will stay below some certain level on the interval [t,T]. Just reference to any literature would be fine, tried to search for it on the internet/books and haven't yet saw it. Thank you in advance

Comment: Recall that GBM is simply the exponent of BM with constant drift. Once you solve your problem for BM with constant drift, you have it solved for GBM as well.

Comment: Thank you very much for quick reply, that should occured to me..